# android Exception is: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "110.8500"

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

In the below code of recyclerView I am increment/decrementing product quantity onClick of respective buttons but app is crashing onClick of increment. I am also calculating product quantity * price but its not working right. Where have I gone wrong? How do I calculate the product price?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RVOrderBrdAdapter.RVViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //getting the product of the specified position
    OrderBrdDataModel product = filteredList.get(position);

    //binding the data with the viewholder views
    holder.brd_value.setText(product.getBrdprice());
    holder.brd_product.setText(product.getBrdname());
    holder.brd_quantity.setText("1");

    holder.brd_increment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            number = Integer.parseInt(holder.brd_quantity.getText().toString());
            if(holder.brd_quantity.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Quantity cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(number >=9999){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Quantity cannot be greater than 9999", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                number++;
                numVal =number++;

            }

            holder.brd_quantity.setText(""+number);
            String b = product.getBrdprice();

           holder.brd_value.setText(Integer.parseInt(b)*numVal);


        }
    });

    holder.brd_decrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            number = Integer.parseInt(holder.brd_quantity.getText().toString());
            if(holder.brd_quantity.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Quantity cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(number<=0){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Quantity cannot be less than 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                number = 0;
            }else {
                number--;
                holder.brd_quantity.setText(""+number);
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return filteredList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return itemFilter;
}

public class RVViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView brd_value, brd_product,brd_quantity,brd_increment,brd_decrement;

    public RVViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        brd_value = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brd_value);
        brd_product = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brd_product);
        brd_quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brd_quantity);
        brd_increment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brd_increment);
        brd_decrement = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brd_decrement);

    }

}
public class ItemFilter extends Filter{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
         ArrayList<OrderBrdDataModel> temp_filteredList= new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<ordList.size();i++){
            if (ordList.get(i).isSelected()){
                temp_filteredList.add(ordList.get(i));
            }

        }
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = temp_filteredList;
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredList = (ArrayList)results.values;
        System.out.println("RvFilter " + filteredList.size());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

}
Below is my crash log

```
2022-10-06 12:06:46.633 11380-11380/com.live I/System.out: crash_report=Exception is: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x6e
2022-10-06 12:15:50.147 12148-12148/com.live I/System.out: crash_report=Exception is: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "110.8500"
```

Comment: *110.8500* is not an integer. It is a decimal value

Comment: @Jens - So changing int to double will solve the  error?

Comment: @Abm yes, that and use Double.parseDouble.

Comment: Yes that should work

Comment: @Jens -  holder.brd_value.setText(Double.parseDouble(b)*numVal); It says Cannot resolve method 'setText(double)'

Comment: @Stultuske - holder.brd_value.setText(Double.parseDouble(b)*numVal); It says Cannot resolve method 'setText(double)'

Comment: First question, can your quantity be a double or should it be an integerß. Second question what is *holder.brd_quantity*?

Comment: BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Variable names must be camelCase not snake_case

Comment: It is double.. holder.brd_quantity is editText binding in recyclerview

Comment: @Abm no doubt you are familiar with String concatenation?

Comment: @Abm You should reformat your double as text

Comment: This line - holder.brd_value.setText(Integer.parseInt(b)*numVal); will also cause crash. It will consider the int resulted as a string id, which does not exist and will then crash. You should change it to holder.brd_value.setText(""+Integer.parseInt(b)*numVal); or any other form of converting the value to string

Comment: @DanBaruch that is indeed the line we've been talking about all along

Comment: @Stultuske ye, only after I've written down the comment I noticed there's a whole conversation here haha

Comment: @DanBaruch -  holder.brd_value.setText(String.valueOf(product.getBrdprice())); This is working fine. Is it the correct way?

Comment: @Abm considering it's different than the original line I don't know if that's the value you are looking for, but yes. It's a correct way.